# Memory effective way to monitor change of Kubernetes objects in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I am working with kubernetes and `kubectl` commands, and am able to get a list of namespaces, and then can get the resources inside those namespaces.  Question is, is there an *effective* way to monitor all resources (CRDs especially) in a certain namespace for changes? I know I could do this:

```
kubectl get myobjecttype -n <user-account-1>
```

and then check timestamps with a separate command, but that seems resource-taxing.

Comment: Hi @OliverWilliams, does the answer from the weibeld answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the Kubernetes [Watch API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes).

In fact, you make a List request (see API reference for e.g. [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#list-pod-v1-core)) and add the `watch=1` query parameter to get a continuous stream of changes to the specified resources.

`kubectl` also supports watches with the `-w/--watch` flag:

```sh
kubectl get myobjecttype -n <user-account-1> -w
```